# Python printing two things on one line

Tags: python

I'm working through the edx python course. I've done everything correctly in the last assignment. However, I'm struggling with this print issue.

I have a function `displayHand(hand)` which essentially takes a dictionary with keys being letters and values be the number of occurrences of the letters. The function then prints a string with each key appearing the same number of times as its value. So for example if

```
hand={a:3, b:4, c:1}
displayHand(hand)=a a a b b b b c
```

Now in the program for any given hand it wants me to display it using the `displayHand` function with the text "current hand: "

Again, if `hand={a:3, b:4, c:1}` the program should display

```
current hand: a a a b b b b c
```

How do I do this with a print statement? I've tried `print("current hand"+str(displayHand(hand))`, but this first evaluates the function and then just prints `None`. I can't put `print("Current Hand: ")` and `displayHand(hand)` directly underneath, because then they print on different lines. I need to get them to print on the same line.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: presumably your `displayHand` function ends with some kind of `print .....` statement? Try ending it with a `return.....` statement instead

Comment: It is assessed on the edx platform so i'm guessing they maybe running python 3.5. Unfortunately i cannot put return in the function because it was a function they provided for you. I'm guessing it's meant to be doable with a just a print statement?

Comment: Is there still something missing/not working? If one of the answers provided works for you, please accept it by clicking on the green check next to it to show others that it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

Python 3:

```
def displayHand(dct):
    for key, val in sorted(dct.items()):  # sorted if key order should be abc
        print((key + " ") * val, end="")


hand = {"a": 3, "b": 4, "c": 1}

print("current hand: ", end="")
displayHand(hand)
```

Notice the `end=""` which appends whatever is inside `""`. The default setting is `end="\n"`. In this case, we will just use an empty string. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function).

Output:

```
current hand: a a a b b b b c
```

Comment: I would not use `dict` as a variable name as it is a reserved name. You could also loop through the dictionary using `key, item` which would avoid the `dict[key]`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, should have been dct. I am usually a lst and dct kind of guy.

Answer (score 1):

That should work for you :

```
print("current hand: ", end="")
displayHand(hand)
```

In print() function default end is new line. In the code above you just change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use print twice, you just have to add a comma after the first print ex: `print("a"), print("b")`.

Comment: This assumes that they're using Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
def displayHand(hand):
    print('{} {}'.format('current hand:', ' '.join([' '.join([li] * ni) for li, ni in sorted(hand.items())])))
```

That creates a string first which is then printed.

Then

```
displayHand(hand)
```

prints the desired output:

```
current hand: a a a b b b b c
```